Attaching effects to Context.AUDIO_SERVICE
I am trying to attach audio effects across all audio and video on my device, and my effects are working on my media player. But, how do you attach it to all sounds?
// Capture the media
manager = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

// If something is being played.
if(manager.isMusicActive()) { 
    MediaPlayer.create(this, sessionId);
    sessionId=manager.generateAudioSessionId();
    // sessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
    System.out.println("==========================       " + sessionId);
    // mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    startService(); // start the background service
    equalizerFragment = EqualizerFragment.newBuilder()
            .setAccentColor(Color.parseColor("#4caf50"))
            .setAudioSessionId(sessionId)
            .build();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.eqFrame, equalizerFragment)
            .commit();
}


